# Problem with OpenIdDict on client side regarding the Redirect_Uri

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, client-side, openiddict

I am using OpenIdDict but having trouble with redirect_uri which stored in my database. The redirect_uri entry in my database is signin-oidc but don't know why have error shown below.

```
   The request address matched a server endpoint: Authorization.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The authorization request was successfully extracted: {
        "client_id": "console",
        "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:6001/signin-oidc",
        "response_type": "code",
        "scope": "openid profile",
        "code_challenge": "Nr0Jgf4cY3jUtC_1w3GwZ2ryR5FeYoSWrYpu7VF2nxQ",
        "code_challenge_method": "S256",
        "response_mode": "form_post",
        "nonce": "637773059511435225.Y2ZkMDY4MzctYjczNi00MmFlLWFiNjEtMmJlOWI1NDllMzNjOTYxY2Q1MmQtNDcyOS00N2RmLTgyZTQtZDg4Yjc0ZDk5ODk4",
        "state": "CfDJ8NYwebNNwH9FkusxDMvbzdrGCOwob0ZBYnanAjf_cGnDjOjF-VnCxbzK8hxyodvDee-v7Sh2Ny4zKhbjOZZZEzSKi-ebQCROJYha2GUiUxbDpvX34Drs-ehjMozt68GkY2ETu_GIf-vRr7Ij4KXaSeUeq5bZioLyJI97kf79txzv700HeEQxxK_unsvj8n8s4fOELMx9dRydCBV0Yw26jROlb-_qjhP9cL1pALEoZ2xeotAl8LY9FZjUDuOuHZSknK-GGFUIhT34-rJ_Wg71MncO-Mat__6m_ISNkr7BIti6qf9qPnLcrTeW-eg6Y_9IK8W_G59ChO1-wwD5Q1A68F086xzGVEvkPLeH1HCGFi0BceBRjRI_Efer9yWJn3pzow",
        "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
        "x-client-ver": "6.11.1.0"
      }.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'h' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
         at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
         at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
         at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
         at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
         at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
```

Comment: According to the error message, it seems there is something wrong when your application codes use System.text,json to read something, I suggest you could check your request or else to find which codes call this read method and what happened when it read the json information.

Comment: Thanks i will have a look again. But I just setting openiddict and never call json parsing function manually.

Comment: I suggest you could also check the startup.cs settings to make sure you don't read the json file to add the OPID connect settings and check the json file's format is right.

Comment: Thank for ur help.. i realized the redirect_urls is an array stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i realized the redirect_urls is an array stored in the database not a single redirect url.